# Yii2 login remember me does not work with FireFox

Tags: php, firefox, cookies, yii2

I have [yii2](/questions/tagged/yii2) app the remember me login checkbox works fine with **Brave** and **Vivaldi** browsers but it does not work with *FireFox*.

In FireFox, it works only if I do not close the browser's window, i.e. closing the tab only.

I tried to check the `_identity` cookie from the developer's tool and its expire date is already after 30 days:

[image]

Is there something special in FireFox that prevents it from retrieving the login? Is there something wrong in the cookie?

I use FireFox ver. 101.0.1 (64-bit) On Kubuntu 20.04.